# Postgresql with golang, questions

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I have created an Api with golang and postgresql as database.

after several requests, the API crashes with an error 500 and a log that displays

> pq : sorry , too many customers already

At first it was because I did not close rows when i select, so i have rows.close() all.

But it's not that because i have already this error.

Then saw the launch of the database takes only 3ms, I thought I should start and close the database on every request to reset all connections, 
but thinking about it a little more, this is nonsense.

So I ask you, how this error works , is that the client connections are reset after a certain time or connection is cut off until a server reboot for client?

If it resets after a certain time , what are the disadvantages of increasing the maximum number of client connection?

My code:

I open my db like this at start of program :

```
    var gest Gestion

    type Gestion struct {
        Db *sql.DB
        DbLog *sql.DB
    }



func InitDbUser() *sql.DB {
      dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
      db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
      LogFatalError(err)
      err2 := db.Ping()
      LogFatalError(err2)
      return db
}

func main() {

    gest.Db = InitDbUser()

        defer gest.Db.Close()
        //routing is here

    }
```

And when i use this request in my psql :

```
select min_val,max_val from pg_settings where name='max_connections';
```

I get hat :

```
 min_val | max_val
---------+---------
 1       | 8388607
```

Sorry for my english, i hope you understand what I ask :)

Comment: Without knowing how you manage your database connections it is hard to guess what is wrong.

Comment: In general you should use a connection pool and ensure you are not concurrently using the same connection.

Comment: how do you do that with go?

Comment: If you are using lib/pq and database/sql then you already get connection pooling. You need to show how you are using your database: where are your queries?

Comment: Ok i have read some docs, i have apply that and it work, i will post a tutoriel because I 'm not the only one to have had this problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the max_connection setting of PG, that might be the problem here:

```
select min_val,max_val from pg_settings where name='max_connections'
```

Comment: Yes i know but i would like to know how it works , I mean at what times the number of client resets ?